# Linear regresion on each raster pixel to predict future month (in R language)

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression, raster

I have successfull run this code. I have read it from:

[Can't Calculate pixel-wise regression in R on raster stack with fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435206/cant-calculate-pixel-wise-regression-in-r-on-raster-stack-with-fun?rq=1)

```
library(raster)

# Example data
r <- raster(nrow=15, ncol=10)
set.seed(0) 

# Now I make 6 raster (1 raster/months), then assign each pixel's value randomly
s <- stack(lapply(1:6, function(i) setValues(r, rnorm(ncell(r), i, 3))))
names(s) <- paste0('Month', c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

# Extract each pixel values 
x <- values(s)

# Model with linreg
m <- lm(Month6 ~ ., data=data.frame(x))

# Prediction raster
p <- predict(s, m)
```

If you run that code, p will be a raster. But, I still confused. How to make raster in the future? For example, I want 'Month8' raster based on 6 previous raster?

What I mean is, each pixels has different linreg equations (where X=Month1, ... , Months6). If I input X=Month8, I will have 150 cells of Y for 8th Month that represent in each pixel of raster.

**What I have done**

```
# Lets try make a data frame for clear insight for my data
x <- values(s)
DF <- data.frame(x)

# Make X as month, and y is target.
library(data.table)
DF_T <- transpose(DF)
Month <- seq(1,nrow(DF_T))
DF_T <- cbind(Month, DF_T)

# Make prediction for first pixel
V1_lr <- lm(V1 ~ Month, data=DF_T)

# prediction for 8th Months in a pixel
V1_p <- predict(V1_lr, data.frame(Month=8))
V1_p
```

This is just one pixel. I want the entire raster for 'Month8'